# Richfaces, error if term has '/'

Tags: java, eclipse, richfaces

I'm facing some kind of error related to richfaces / eclipse or something else...
I'm using a predicate to make a conjunction for a search, all fields work great, in exception of one that has "/" on the text field, I'll put an example..

1- The search term is '1234' result ok...
2- The search term is '5678' result ok... (Only if I split term...)
3- The search term is '1234/5678'... page kinda blinks, no error nor result

If I try to debug, debugger stops for case 1 and 2, but won't stop in case 3..

Im using this code...

```
public Collection<FormTram> findForms(DataCons form) {
    final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<FormTram> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(FormTram.class);
    final Root<FormTram> criteria = criteriaQuery.from(FormTram.class);
    Predicate conjunction = cb.conjunction();

    if (form.getIdOrder() != "") {
        String[] tokens = form.getIdOrder().split("/");
        for (String t : tokens){
            conjunction.getExpressions().add(cb.like(criteria.get("order").get("plOrder").get("idOrder").as(String.class), "%"+ t +"%"));
        }

    criteriaQuery.orderBy(cb.asc(criteria.get("idForm")));
    return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```

Edited to give more code, but I don't think it will make a difference..
This is not real code, just renamed some variables to give context.
Will appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't get your code, t is not used (also, you should give your variables a meaningful name).

Comment: Edited, t is used now, was my mistake... Hope you can get my code now

Comment: Since the issue is probably with the incoming String the code doesn't look relevant. What is DataCons? Is that your bean? What RichFaces component are you using?

Comment: Tha'ts why I put less code in the beginning, I'm using RichFaces 4.3.7, DataCons is a custom DataType that I use for the search feature in the bean, It's a webform where I can add search terms like order number, order type, start/end, etc. Then in this ejb I use predicate to make the magic, the thing is that when i put "normal" text in that idOrder (declared string) and hit search, have a result (and that works as intended). but if i have "/" in the string, when i want to search the screen blinks and I have no results, but if i put the left (or right) part I have a result (as intended).

Comment: Yeah, but don't know what is happening to the string before it gets to the code you're showing. Is `form getIdOrder()` returning the correct string?

Comment: I have a searchForm.xhtml, and a searchBean.java. I tried to put a breakpoint in the bean, so when i press "search" i can see what's in the string, but never got there... That's why i said problem must be with richfaces or something like that...